# Starting React App from pulled github project

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

I've pulled a github repository containing code for a reactjs app into one of my directories but I can't find a way to run the app on my computer. I can start a new app using create-react-app but I can't/(don't know how to) use the existing app for instead ofa freshly created one.

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04.3 on a virtual machine, my node version is 4.2.6. 
I've tried **sudo apt-get install --only-upgrade nodejs** but it simply says my node version is already up to date. (I include this because npm start gives me a bunch of errors and tells me that it may be because I might have to update node) but the app I create with create-react-app works fine?
The error:
[image]
Package.json:

```
{
    "name": "my-app",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
        "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
        "express": "^4.16.2",
        "package.json": "^2.0.1",
        "prop-types": "^15.6.0",
        "react": "^16.0.0",
        "react-bootstrap": "^0.31.5",
        "react-dom": "^16.0.0",
        "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
        "react-scripts": "1.0.14",
        "uuid": "^3.1.0",
        "webpack": "^3.8.1"
        },
    "scripts": {
        "start": "react-scripts start",
        "build": "react-scripts build",
        "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
        "eject": "react-scripts eject"
        },
    "devDependencies": {
        "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
        "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1"
        }
}
```

Comment: First you should probably read the readme. Then if it's empty, explore the package.json to see what are the available scripts you can run.

Comment: thnks, the readme is empty, so I looked in package.json; it has start, build, test, and eject under scripts. ("start": "react-scripts start" and so on)

Comment: then `npm run start` should do the trick.

Comment: can you show the package.json?

Comment: I will update the question the error and package.json

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Carry out the following steps:

```
//Step 1:
git clone [repository url]

//Step 2:
cd [local repository]
```

```
//Step 3:
//Check package.json file and ensure scripts are notated as below:

"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
```

```
//Step 4: 
/* Delete the node_modules folder and any 'lock' files such as 
yarn.lock or package-lock.json if present.*/

//Step 5: 
npm install

//Step 6:
npm start
```

To Note: *There can be some conflict between **yarn** and **npm** when cloning from certain repositories. It's best to assume that every repo may need trimming before ultimately running `npm install`. I tested the above steps several times under several different factors. This is the best I have so far.*

Comment: Sometime we can use `yarn start` command to run react app.Mostly it is possible if they configured `yarn` as package manager and if they already installed `yarn` installed on their pc.

Comment: Thanks @Sinapcs. This reply works for me.

Comment: step 4 is most helpful

Answer (score 2):

In case of issues shown after npm install, run the below to automatically fix the issues:

```
npm audit fix
```

Alternatively, use the below to see the errors:

```
npm audit
```